# React native WebView can't trigger css and js files

Tags: html, css, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I'm trying to nest html5 to react native by using webview, but it seems like I can't trigger the css and js file, my react native js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet  } from 'react-native';

import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';


export default Game = () =>  {


return (

  <WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={require('./index.html')}
    style={styles.container}
  />

 );
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
 flex: 1,
 padding: 300,
 paddingTop: 500,
 },

});
```

my html code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>15 Puzzle</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./15-puzzle.css"> 
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="puzzle"></div>
   <div id="controls">
       <button id="solve">Solve</button>        
       <button id="scramble">Scramble</button>
   </div>

   <p>Developed by Arnis Ritia</p>
   <p><a href="https://github.com/arnisritins/15-Puzzle">View source code on GitHub</a></p>

   <script src="./15-puzzle.js"></script>
```

I just can't trigger the css and js code in html, does webview support it?

Answer (score 0):

This way is not working for WebView.
you must create a file or a string for html content like this:
For example create file rawHTML:

```
export const html = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>15 Puzzle</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./15-puzzle.css"> 
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="puzzle"></div>
   <div id="controls">
       <button id="solve">Solve</button>        
       <button id="scramble">Scramble</button>
   </div>

   <p>Developed by Arnis Ritia</p>
   <p><a href="https://github.com/arnisritins/15-Puzzle">View source code on GitHub</a></p>

   <script src="./15-puzzle.js"></script>
</body>
</head>
`
```

and then import this in js file like this:

```
import {html} from './rawHTML';
```

and change WebView source to `source={{html: html}}`

Comment: It is he same thing, I tried this before, it can't trigger the css and js parts